# Simply extracting multiple records from multiple other records...(Rails/Ruby)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I think this is a simple problem, but i just cant get my head round the solution. If i have a collection of records (reports in this case):

```
@reports = Report.all,  :conditions => ["score > 10"]
```

and then i try to find the associated collection of other type of records (users in this case) i, naively, try this - but know from the offset that it wont work:

```
@users = User.find   :all,  :conditions => ["id IN (?)", @results.user_id]
```

So, how do i efficiently extract the @users collection of records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `User has_many :reports`

```
@users = User.joins(:reports) # all users that have reports
```

If you only want all users for some specific reports

```
@users = User.joins(:reports).where("reports.id IN (?)", @reports.map(&:id))
```

Comment: I answered toy your question directly, although you might want to use associations and eager loading ie. `@reports = Reports.includes(:users)`